# \377 character in c

Tags: c, file-read

I am trying to read a file in c.
I have a `.txt` file and it has that content:

```
file_one.txt file_two.txt file_three.txt file_four.txt
```

When I try to read this file with `fopen` I get this output:

```
file_one.txt file_two.txt file_three.txt file_four.txt\377
```

What does `\377` mean? Here's my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){

        FILE *filelist;

        char ch;

        filelist=fopen("file-path", "rt");

        while (!feof(filelist)) {
            ch = getc(filelist);
            printf("%c",ch);
        }

        fclose(filelist);

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `getc()` function returns a result of type `int`, not of type `char`.  Your `char ch;` should be `int ch;`.

Why does it return an `int`? Because the value it returns is *either* the character it just read (as an `unsigned char` converted to `int`) *or* the special value `EOF` (typically -1) to indicate either an input error or an end-of-file condition.

Don't use the `feof()` function to detect the end of input. It returns true only *after* you've run out of input. Your last call to `getc()` is returning `EOF`, which when stored into a `char` object is converted to `(char)-1`, which is typically `'\377'`.

Another problem is that `feof()` will *never* return a true value if there was an input error; in that case, `ferror()` will return true. Use `feof()` and/or `ferror()` *after* `getc()` returns `EOF`, to tell *why* it returned `EOF`.

To read from a file until you reach the end of it:

```
int ch;
while ((ch = getc(filelist)) != EOF) {
    /* ch contains the last character read; do what you like with it */
}
```

Suggested reading: Section 12 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: while ((ch = getc(filelist)) != EOF)
        printf("%c",ch);
i run this code and it worked.But ch var is int how come the output would be string?

Comment: does ch variable holds the ascii value of char in every step of reading?

Comment: @user1772101: Yes (assuming the system uses ASCII).

Answer (score 16):

The `\377` is an octal escape sequence, decimal 255, all bits set. It comes from converting `EOF` - which usually has the value `-1` - to a `char`, due to

```
while (!feof(filelist)) {
```

`feof(filelist)` only becoming true *after* you have tried to read past the file.

So at the end of the file, you enter the loop once more, and the `getc()` returns `EOF`.